# table column as variable

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm getting a syntax error in my stored procedure when trying to use a variable as a reference to a tables column.

```
BEGIN
SET @mycolumn = (SOME SELECT STATEMENT RETURNING MY COLUMN);
SELECT a.@mycolumn FROM mytable as a;
END
```

**Question:** What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: remove `as a` from the end of the 3rd line

Comment: @vkp I will be using it in a `JOIN` statement so need it to be alias'd

Comment: What is your syntax error?  Don't be shy.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's just states you have an error here `a.@mycolumn`

Comment: I'm guessing it needs to be `CONCAT`'d with the `a`? but is there another way?

Comment: Just use `SELECT @mycolumn`  The result of the query is stored in the variable, not a pointer to a table column.

Comment: @Siyual yes but I'm using it in a `JOIN` so specifically looking for a way using `table.col` syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do dynamic SQL.  Here is one way to do it:

```
BEGIN
SET @mycolumn = (SOME SELECT STATEMENT RETURNING MY COLUMN);
DECLARE @sql varchar(20000); 
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT a.', @mycolumn, ' FROM mytable as a';
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: I like this, but I just tried using a simple `SELECT * FROM mytable` and it failed from a syntax error, the error just gives the `DECLARE` line

Comment: I had to use `PREPARE` AND `EXECUTE` running MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Jordan,

You might need to use table variable or Dynamic SQL for this.

Here is how I do this with table variable.

```
Declare @table as table (columnName dataType.

Insert into @table 

SOME SELECT STATEMENT RETURNING YOUR COLUMN
```

Results by running the below query:-

```
SELECT * FROM @table
```

Comment: Yea I'm using it in a join and will need the `table.col` syntax

Comment: Ones you have the table variable then you can use it in your join. :- ; select T.columnNAME from @table as T  INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS T2 ON T.columnName = T2.Columnname